# Как переименовывать через консоль браузера?

Tags: javascript, html, консоль, браузер

Сразу извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, никакого ЯП не знаю, и гугл ничего толкового не выдал. Если речь про консоль того же браузера, то как через неё что нибудь переименовать? Например кнопку, слово, ещё что? Полагаю, сперва должно идти

document.getElementById('тут элемент') а вот что дальше?

Comment: Вам сначала нужно понять что такое html и css и как вообще создаётся графический интерфейс в браузере

Comment: Что значит *переименовать*? Если поменять текст для кнопки\ссылки, то например `document.querySelector('.js-edit-post.js-gps-track').textContent = 'hello'` переименует кнопку *Править* под вашим вопросом.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть id, например

```
<button id="btn">Сохранить</button>
```

то

```
document.getElementById('btn').innerHtml('Удалить')
```

Если id нет, то надо выбирать по другим свойствам (класс, родители и т.п.) - это уже сложнее нужно понимать CSS селекторы.